# How to add sum multiple statements in a while loop in Java

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm a beginner when it comes to java. I have a simple java programming assignment. Here is the bases of the program:

"Best Purchase is accepting online orders for electronic devices and accessories. They have developed a program that allows the user to select the device(s) to purchase from a menu of items. Write a program that allows the user (customer) to select items to purchase, calculates the price of the items ordered, and displays a receipt of this information to the customer (assume the sales tax rate is 6.5%)"

Your program should prompt the user (customer) to enter the following information:

- Customer name
- Electronic devices and accessories purchased

The program then outputs the following information:

- Customer’s name
- Total number of items ordered
- Price of menu items before sales tax
- Sales tax
- Total amount due

Here is my issue how to i add the values inside my nested if depending on what numbers the user select?

Ex: The the user selects 1,2,3,10(To exit Loop)

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class OnlinePurchase {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        //Declare Variables
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sCustomerName ="";   //Stores the Customer's Name
        int nSelection = 0;         //Stores the value entered by the user
        int nSum = 0;               //Stores sum of values entered
        int nCount = 0;             //Number of values entered
        int nPrice = 0;

        //Declare Constants
        final int SENTINEL = 10; //Used to end loop

        //Promt User to enter the their name.
        System.out.print("Please enter the your name: ");
        //Read Customer Name input from user
        sCustomerName = input.nextLine( );    

        //Print to Blank Line for spacing
        System.out.println("\n");

        //Print Purchase Menu
        System.out.println("BEST PURCHASE PRODUCTS:");
        System.out.println("1. Smartphone..........$249");
        System.out.println("2. Smartphone Case.... $39");
        System.out.println("3. PC Laptop...........$1149");
        System.out.println("4. Tablet..............$349");
        System.out.println("5. Tablet Case.........$49");
        System.out.println("6. eReader.............$119");
        System.out.println("7. PC Desktop..........$889");
        System.out.println("8. LED Monitor.........$299");
        System.out.println("9. Laser Printer.......$399");
        System.out.println("10.Complete my order");

        //Print to Blank Line for spacing
        System.out.println("\n");

        while (nSelection != SENTINEL) {

            //Calculate sum
            nSum = nPrice + nSum;

            //Increment counter
            nCount++; //or nCount = nCount + 1;

            //Promt User to enter the an item from the menu.
            System.out.print("Please enter item from the menu above: ");
            //Read input from user for selected purchase
            nSelection = input.nextInt();

            if (nSelection == 1) {

                nPrice = 249;

                //Promt User to enter the an item from the menu.
                System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above: ");
                //Read input from user for selected purchase
                nSelection = input.nextInt();
            }
            else if (nSelection == 2 ) {

                nPrice = 39;

                //Promt User to enter the an item from the menu.
                System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above: ");
                //Read input from user for selected purchase
                nSelection = input.nextInt();
            }
            else if (nSelection == 3 ) {

                nPrice = 1149; 

                //Promt User to enter the an item from the menu.
                System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above: ");
                //Read input from user for selected purchase
                nSelection = input.nextInt();
            }
            else if (nSelection == 4 ) {

                  nPrice = 349;

                  //Promt User to enter the an item from the menu.
                  System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above: ");
                  //Read input from user for selected purchase
                  nSelection = input.nextInt();
            }
            else if (nSelection == 5 ) {

                nPrice = 49;

                //Promt User to enter the an item from the menu.
                System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above: ");
                //Read input from user for selected purchase
                nSelection = input.nextInt();
            }
            else if (nSelection == 6 ) {

                nPrice = 119;

                //Promt User to enter the an item from the menu.
                System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above: ");
                //Read input from user for selected purchase
                nSelection = input.nextInt();
            }
            else if (nSelection == 7 ) {

                nPrice = 899;

                //Promt User to enter the an item from the menu.
                System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above: ");
                //Read input from user for selected purchase
                nSelection = input.nextInt();
            }
            else if (nSelection == 8 ) {

                nPrice = 299;

                //Promt User to enter the an item from the menu.
                System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above: ");
                //Read input from user for selected purchase
                nSelection = input.nextInt();
            }  
            else if (nSelection == 9 ) {

                nPrice = 399;

                //Promt User to enter the an item from the menu.
                System.out.print("Please enter another item from the menu above: ");
                //Read input from user for selected purchase
                nSelection = input.nextInt();
            }
        }//end while user did not enter 10

        //Print blank line
        System.out.println();

        //Print Thank You message
        System.out.println("Thank you for ordering with Best Purchase,"+sCustomerName);
        //Print number of integers entered
        System.out.println("Total Items Ordered: " + nCount);
         //Print number of integers entered
        System.out.println("Total: $" + nSum);  
    }//end main class
}//end public class
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a homework completion service.

Comment: First, if you want to allow the users to select multiple items, you have to run your logic in a loop. Second, instead of `nPrice = 119;` you can do `nPrice += 119;` - for example...

Comment: @redFIVE Did you fully read his question? he didn't ask us to do his HW. You should retract your downvote.

Comment: Isn't your code doing already what you asked? You've already have a loop and you're already adding the values of the items...

Comment: @alfasin, requirements dump, code dump + `Here is my issue how to i add the values inside my nested if depending on what numbers the user select?`. How is this not a homework completion request? Also, I'll downvote however I please.

Comment: @redFIVE take it easy - it was a recommendation not a command :) seems like we read the same thing and interpret it differently, I see a question of how to add functionality to an existing code, and you see someone who asks people to write his HW for him. Opinions vary, happens. All the best!

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, your code is over complicated and there is a lot of duplication.
You should take advantage of methods for reuse and maybe a switch statement to handle choosing the right price. Also, you should not place all of your program logic in the main method - take advantage of smaller, more concise methods and minimize what you place in main().

Your while loop should simply accept the next line of input, call a processItem() method and terminate if the number entered is your Sentinel value (10).

Try this revision of your code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OnlinePurchase {

    String customerName;
    int nSum = 0;               //Stores sum of values entered
    int nCount = 0;             //Number of values entered

    public void printPurchaseMenu(){
        //Print Purchase Menu
        System.out.println("\nBEST PURCHASE PRODUCTS:");
        System.out.println("1. Smartphone..........$249");
        System.out.println("2. Smartphone Case.... $39");
        System.out.println("3. PC Laptop...........$1149");
        System.out.println("4. Tablet..............$349");
        System.out.println("5. Tablet Case.........$49");
        System.out.println("6. eReader.............$119");
        System.out.println("7. PC Desktop..........$889");
        System.out.println("8. LED Monitor.........$299");
        System.out.println("9. Laser Printer.......$399");
        System.out.println("10.Complete my order");
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String name){
        customerName = name;
    }

    public void processInput(int inputValue){

        switch(inputValue){
          case 1: addItem(249); break;
          case 2: addItem(39); break;
          case 3: addItem(1149); break;
          case 4: addItem(349); break;
          case 5: addItem(49); break;
          case 6: addItem(119); break;
          case 7: addItem(889); break;
          case 8: addItem(299); break;
          case 9: addItem(399); break;
          case 10: printResults(); break;
          default: System.out.println("You entered an invalid value.");
        }
    }

    public void addItem(int price){
        nSum += price;
        nCount++;
    }

    public void printResults(){
        //Print Thank You message
        System.out.println("\nThank you for ordering with Best Purchase," + customerName);
        //Print number of integers entered
        System.out.println("Total Items Ordered: " + nCount);
         //Print number of integers entered
        System.out.println("Total: $" + nSum);
    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        OnlinePurchase onlinePurchase = new OnlinePurchase();

        //Declare Variables
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nSelection = 0;  //Stores the value entered by the user

        //Declare Constants
        final int SENTINEL = 10; //Used to end loop

        //Prompt User to enter the their name.
        System.out.print("Please enter the your name: ");

        //Read Customer Name input from user
        onlinePurchase.setCustomerName(input.nextLine( ));

        //Print Purchase Menu
        onlinePurchase.printPurchaseMenu();

        while (nSelection != SENTINEL){
            System.out.print("Please enter item from the menu above: ");
            nSelection = input.nextInt();

            onlinePurchase.processInput(nSelection);
            System.out.println("\n");
      }//end while user did not enter 10
  }//end main method
}//end public class
```